# How to push object into an array? in Angular 7

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-forms, array-splice, formgroups

I am pushing an object into an array but cannot do it?

I'm doing it like this

```
this.passData = this.tribeForm.value;
    var id = {"tribe_id": 1}
    this.passData.push(id)
```

This is the value in the tribeForm

[image]

I also tried

```
var id = {tribe_id: 1}
```

and

```
this.passData.splice(0,0, id)
```

and

```
this.passData = Array.prototype.slice(id)
```

and

```
this.passData.concat(id)
```

but it all ends up with

```
TypeError: this.passData.push/splice/concat is not a function
```

Comment: `tribeForm` is not an array, it's an object. You can not push/concat/slice an object. What instead you can do is `this.passData['id']=id`

Comment: can you show this.passData value

Comment: `if (!this.passData) this.passData=[id] else this.passData.push(id)`. NOTE: in typescript not use var, use let or constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not that clear, But I understood you are manipulating form data, value of form data returns an Object, Not an array. Objects in JavaScript are represented as key-value pairs, (or attribute-value) pairs.

Example :

```
var object = {
  name : "Jhon", 
  grade : 12,
  gpa : 8.12
}
```

It is just a collection of key-value pairs, push(), concat() and other methods are supported only for Arrays not for Objects. You can achieve whatever you want simply by creating a new key/attribute and assigning the value to it.

```
this.passData = this.tribeForm.value
this.passData['tribe_id'] = 1
//or, Objects can also contain nested object
this.passData['someKey'] = {'tribe_id' : 1}
```

You can create an empty array and push objects to it

Example :

```
var exampleArray = []
exampleArray.push({'tribe_id' : 1})
```

Now, it works because exampleArray is an Array not JS object.

Thanks for A2A

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand the error:

```
TypeError: this.passData.push/splice/concat is not a function
```

**`Push/splice/concat`** is functions for **`Array`** and because of that the console is yelling at you that the `passData` is not an `Array`.

Make sure your `passData` is an Array and you will able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple answer with multiply object case too.

```
      this.passData.push({ tribe_id: 1, name: "lorm ipsum" });
```